# WGET saves with wrong file and extension name possibly due to BASH

Tags: bash, url, curl, wget, forum

I`ve tried this on a few forum threads already.
However I keep on getting the some failure as a result.

To replicate the problem :

Here is an url leading to a forum thread with 6 pages.

```
http://forex.kbpauk.ru/showflat.php/Cat/0/Number/107623/page/0/fpart/1/vc/1
```

What I typed into the console was :

```
wget "http://forex.kbpauk.ru/showflat.php/Cat/0/Number/107623/page/0/fpart/{1..6}/vc/1"
```

And here is what I got:

```
      --2018-06-14 10:44:17--  http://forex.kbpauk.ru/showflat.php/Cat/0/Number/107623/page/0/fpart/%7B1..6%7D/vc/1
    Resolving forex.kbpauk.ru (forex.kbpauk.ru)... 185.68.152.1
    Connecting to forex.kbpauk.ru (forex.kbpauk.ru)|185.68.152.1|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: unspecified [text/html]
    Saving to: '1'

1                                    [  <=>                                       ]  19.50K  58.7KB/s    in 0.3s

2018-06-14 10:44:17 (58.7 KB/s) - '1' saved [19970]
```

The file was saved as simply "1" with no extension as it seems.

My expectations were that the file will be saved with an .html extension, because its a webpage.

Im trying to get WGET to work, but if its possible to do what I want with CURL than I would also accept that as an answer.

Comment: Additionally here is another forum thread :
https://www.forexfactory.com/showthread.php?t=769466&page=2
I get the same problem with the file name being messed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's a couple of issues with what you're trying to do.

1. The double quotes around your URL actually prevent Bash expansion, so you're not really downloading 6 files, but a single URL with "{1..6}" in it. You probably want to not have quotes around the URL to allow bash to expand it into 6 different parameters.
2. I notice that all of the pages are called "1", irrespective of their actual page numbers. This means the server is always serving a page with the same name, making it very hard for Wget or any other tool to actually make a copy of the webpage.

The real way to create a mirror of the forum would be to use this command line:

`$ wget -m --no-parent -k --adjust-extension http://forex.kbpauk.ru/showflat.php/Cat/0/Number/107623/page/0/fpart/1`

Let me explain what this command does:

`-m` `--mirror` activates the mirror mode (recursion)
`--no-parent` asks Wget to not go above the directory it starts from
`-k` `--convert-links` will edit the HTML pages you download so that the links in them will point to the other local pages you have also downloaded. This allows you to browse the forum pages locally without needing to be online
`--adjust-extension` This is the option you were originally looking for. It will cause Wget to save the file with a `.html` extension if it downloads a `text/html` file but the server did not provide an extension.

Comment: Thanks allot !))
This is a perfect solution !

Answer (score 1):

simply use the `-O` switch to specify the output filename, otherwise wget just defaults to something like in your case its `1`

so if you wanted to call your file `what-i-want-to-call-it.html` then you would do

```
 wget "http://forex.kbpauk.ru/showflat.php/Cat/0/Number/107623/page/0/fpart/{1..6}/vc/1" -o what-i-want-to-call-it.html
```

if you type into the console `wget --help` you will get a full list of all the options that wget provides

To verify it has worked type the following to output

```
cat what-i-want-to-call-it.html
```

Comment: recently updated answer, I accidentally used a lower case -o to begin with, when it should have been an uppercase -O

Comment: Thanks ) Atleast now I`m able to download manually.
Do you know if theres a way to set file names to multiple files ?

For example a command to download 6 pages (page={1..6})
and name them like : page1, page2, page3, etc ?